# Remove all files under 600 bytes

Tags: shell, unix

I've seen questions about how I can remove all files under a certain file size, but none of them have dealt with very small files (most of mine are simple .txt files that contain 500-1200 characters).  All of the solutions I've seen so far look something like

```
find . -size -1k -delete
```

I've tried using the following:

```
find . -size -600
find . -size -600b
find . -size -0.6k
```

None of which worked,  can someone tell me how to make this method work for smaller file sizes?  (I'm sure I'm just missing a trailing character after the 600)

Answer (score 5):

`c` is the size specifier for bytes, it means characters. The `b` variant that you may *think* would work is actually for blocks (of 512 bytes each).

It's all contained in detail in the manpage for `find`:

```
-size n[cwbkMG]
    File uses n units of space.  The following suffixes can be used:
        'b'  for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is used)
        'c'  for bytes
        'w'  for two-byte words
        'k'  for Kilobytes (units of 1024 bytes)
        'M'  for Megabytes (units of 1048576 bytes)
        'G'  for Gigabytes (units of 1073741824 bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
find . -size -600c
```

for bytes

Comment: that would make sense, don't know why I didn't think of that.  thanks!